# How to sum cumulative days an account is active from a table with multiple date ranges per account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a transactional table that has account, TN number, provision status, transaction status, and date. An account is considered active if it has at least one TN number that provisioned successfully and no de-provision status.

Each account can be active for a period of time, then de-provision the last active TN and it becomes inactive. But that account can be active again if aTN is provisioned successfully.

I need to sum the cumulative days an account has been active with at least one TN in a provisioned state.

Here is a sample of my transaction table.

```
ACCOUNT TN_NUMBER   STATUS      TRANSACTION_STATUS  DATE
------- ---------   --------------  ------------------  ----------
1234    8005551212  Provisioned     Success     2019-05-17
1234    8665558989  Provisioned     Success     2019-05-25
1234    8005551212  De-provisioned  Success     2019-05-27
1234    8665558989  De-provisioned  Failed      2019-06-03
1234    8665558989  De-provisioned  Success     2019-06-05
1234    8005551212  Provisioned     Success     2019-06-01
5678    8005557777  Provisioned     Success     2019-01-01
5678    8005557777  De-provisioned  Success     2019-05-01
```

Account 1234 started 2019-05-17, deprovisioned the last TN on that account on 2019-06-05. (14 days active)
Then that account was active again starting 2019-06-01 and remains active. (61 days active).

Account 5678 was active 4 days.

This needs to be a daily query on 1.7 million accounts.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the sample data, that is very helpful! Not bad for your first post! Can you show what you have tried, where you are having trouble, and any errors you are getting with your code?

Comment: And what results you want!

Answer (score 1):

Use a cumulative sum to get the number of provisioned accounts at each point in time.  Then assign a "grouping" by counting the number of unprovisioned accounts less than each row:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when num_provisioned <= 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by account order by date) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Provisioned'
                      then 1
                      when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Provisioned'
                      then 1
                      when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Unprovisioned'
                      then -1
                      else 0
                 end) over (partition by account order by date) as num_provisioned
      from t
     ) t
```

With this information, it is then a matter of a couple of aggregations and a `lead()` (to get the next deprovisioning):

```
with g as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when num_provisioned <= 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by account order by date) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Provisioned'
                            then 1
                            when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Provisioned'
                            then 1
                            when transaction_status = 'Success' and status = 'Unprovisioned'
                            then -1
                            else 0
                       end) over (partition by account order by date) as num_provisioned
            from t
           ) t
      )
select account,
       sum(datediff(day, min_date, coalesce(max_date, getdate()))) as num_days
from (select account, grouping, max(num_provisioned) as num_provisioned,
             min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date,
             lead(min(date)) over (partition by account order by min(date)) as next_min_date
      from g
      group by account, grouping
     ) g
where num_provisioned > 0
group by account;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple aggregation:

```
select  t1.Account,
        sum(datediff(day,t1.[date],t2.[date])) as NumDays
from #t1 as t1
    inner join #t1 as t2 ON t1.Account = t2.Account and t1.TN_NUMBER = t2.TN_NUMBER
where t1.status = 'Provisioned'
  and t1.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'Success'
  and t2.status = 'De-provisioned'
  and t2.TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'Success'
  and t1.[Date] <= t2.[Date]
group by t1.Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your question : 2019-06-05 is after 2019-06-01 so the account 1234 is provisioned without interruption from 2019-05-17 until today, and there is 4 monts (not days) between 2019-01-01 and 2019-05-01.

Here is my script. I think it's quicker if you have a lot of data.

```
WITH PRO AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM DBO.[TRANSACTION]
    WHERE STATUS = 'Provisioned'
            AND TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'Success' ), 
DEPRO AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM DBO.[TRANSACTION]
    WHERE STATUS = 'De-provisioned'
            AND TRANSACTION_STATUS = 'Success' ), 
-- Create interval for transactions
INTERVAL AS (
    SELECT T1.ACCOUNT, T1.DATE AS BEGIN_DATE, ISNULL(T2.DATE,CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())) AS END_DATE
    FROM PRO T1
    LEFT JOIN DEPRO T2
        ON T1.TN_NUMBER = T2.TN_NUMBER
            AND T1.DATE < T2.DATE ) ,
-- Create concatenated intervals 
INTERVAL_CONCAT (ACCOUNT, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) AS (
    SELECT ACCOUNT,BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE
    FROM INTERVAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I1.ACCOUNT, I2.BEGIN_DATE, I1.END_DATE
    FROM INTERVAL I1
    INNER JOIN INTERVAL_CONCAT I2
        ON I1.ACCOUNT = I2.ACCOUNT
            AND I1.BEGIN_DATE < I2.END_DATE
            AND I1.END_DATE > I2.END_DATE ),
-- Remove duplicates 
INTERVAL_RN AS (
    SELECT *, RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE ORDER BY  ACCOUNT)
    FROM INTERVAL_CONCAT ), 
INTERVAL_WO_DUP AS (
    SELECT ACCOUNT, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE
    FROM INTERVAL_RN
    WHERE RN=1 ),
-- Remove underlying intervals 
INTERVAL_CLEANING AS ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM INTERVAL_WO_DUP 
    EXCEPT
    SELECT I2.*
    FROM INTERVAL_WO_DUP I1
    INNER JOIN INTERVAL_WO_DUP I2
        ON I2.BEGIN_DATE < I1.END_DATE
            AND I2.BEGIN_DATE>= I1.BEGIN_DATE
            AND I2.END_DATE <=I1.END_DATE
            AND NOT (I2.BEGIN_DATE = I1.BEGIN_DATE AND I2.END_DATE=I1.END_DATE))

SELECT ACCOUNT, SUM(DATEDIFF(D,BEGIN_DATE,END_DATE)) AS PROVISIONED_DURATION
FROM INTERVAL_CLEANING
GROUP BY  ACCOUNT
```

ResultSet with your data

```
ACCOUNT PROVISIONED_DURATION
------- --------------------
1234    95
5678    120
```